# syntax error near unexpected token `(' python script

Tags: python, linux

I am running a python code that has to interact between a windows machine and a linux machine.

The code is launched on windows, the computations are performed by the server, and the result comes back in a folder on windows.

When I run the code on my Windows machine is fine but when this is passed through the linux server I get the following error message:

```
 line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 line 25: `db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.18", # host
```

while the line of code is:

```
 db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.18", # host
```

What does the error message mean and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually running your Python code *as Python*...

Comment: the closing parenthesis is in the next line of code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python file needs to be executed by the Python interpreter.

You can do e.g.:

```
python script.py
```

where `script.py` is the name of your file.

What you are doing instead is running your Python script through Bash (in fact, what you are getting is a typical Bash error). Probably this is happening because you are using `./script.py`, but your script is missing the correct [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

Indeed, if yours is a Python 3 script, you should use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: I tried but now I get: /home/scripts/running_jobs/job_2953875.sh: line 5: /home/scripts/pyscripts/Carriers_Weekly_Breakdown_Comparison.py: Permission denied

Comment: I guess that you have chosen to add the shebang line and I guess that `Carriers_Weekly_Breakdown_Comparison.py` is missing the executable bit. If this is correct, then `chmod +x Carriers_Weekly_Breakdown_Comparison.py`.

Answer (score 1):

When executing python script in a remote server , you need to create .sh file , give location of python script inside that .sh file. then execute the sh file.

The whole process looks like :

- create a .sh file using some editor (vi,echo) i.e.  **vi any_name.sh**
- inside the sh file . copy paste

  **#!/usr/bin/env python**

  **python /home/..../script_folder/your_script_name.py**
- Now save and quit the editor, and enter command : **./any_name.sh**

It's because while executing python code in servers , they mostly accept .sh only. Inside the .sh file , we tell computer to execute the python script using the python inerpreter.